# Encountering offset for logical block address in libusb using xusb.c example code?

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I'm using the example file xusb.c in the libusb library to talk to a flash drive and have modified the command descriptor block of the read(10) in the test_mass_storage function by setting bytes 2-5 to set the logical block address parameter. However, I'm getting a weird result with the returned sector / block address, with:

```
cdb[2] = 0x00;
cdb[3] = 0x00;
cdb[4] = 0x00;
cdb[5] = 0x61;
```

returning sector / block address 1 of the disk, 0x62 is sector 2, etc. Nothing in the documentation I can find suggests there should by an offset of 0x60 or 96.. so is this device specific, an error in the code, or something in the specification?

[read(10) structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx12z.png)

Comment: Most USB block devices contain a partition table. You might have the 0x60 blocks as the offset of the first partition.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. So if I were to reformat it with varying software the offset of the first partition could potentially change?

Comment: Most tools don't change the partitioning when formatting, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm delving into the fat32 filesystem, the issue became apparent. I was opening the drive as a logical disk using HxD which I was using as a method of comparison to the xusb.c output. This started the sector count at the beginning of the volume rather than the start of the physical drive. Opening the drive under the Physical Disk tab resolved the issue.